# How to set a cookie from an ASMX web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, cookies, asmx

I have an ASP.Net web application and an ASMX web service that will be called in the WebApp. I want my web service to store a cookie when it is called by the WebApp. Then read the cookie in the WebApp, after calling the web service. 
I wrote this code for my web service, it run without problem, but when I come back to my WebApp, there isn't any cookie in the context.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public string MyWebMethod()
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CookieName", "abc");
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
    Context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
}
```

Comment: You will not be able to read the cookies across application as long as they are created and read by the applications belonging to the same domain? Can you share how your web app and web service are hosted and how web app is calling the web service?

Comment: Each of them is placed by IIS on a different website(port) of a server. web app calls the WS in server side.

Comment: Do you store the cookies received from the WS, and add them again in subsequent WS calls?

Comment: If you're using `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest` in your client, be aware that cookies are not maintained between requests, you must manually handle the `CookieContainer`. Are you sure the headers and cookies are being set? What does the raw HTTP traffic show?

Comment: Also, why are you using ASMX?

Comment: @devio I want to save the cookie in the user's browser, by the WS, not the client. Did you mean the client should receive and store them?

Comment: @Dai I don't know the type of method of client (WebClient or HttpWebRequest) . I add the WS by adding service reference to the project in VS. then create an object of service reference and call WS web methods on this object.

Comment: @Dai what is your offer instead of ASMX?